# pass ansible variable to powershell code that contains curly braces

Tags: powershell, variables, ansible, curly-braces

I want to integrate in an ansible task the execution of powershell command containing an ansible variable with the win_shell module or i always get the error *"template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'std'"*.  However, I tried to add quotes and double quotes but nothing helped. Here is the task with the powershell code:

```
- name: add windows key
  win_shell: |
    $kms = '{{kms}}'
    $OSversion = (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
    switch -Regex ($OSversion) {
      'Windows Server 2016 Standard'   {$key = {{ key1 }};break}
      'Windows Server 2016 Datacenter' {$key = {{ key2 }};break}
      'Windows Server 2019 Datacenter' {$key = {{ key3 }};break}
    }
    $KMSservice = Get-WMIObject -query "select * from SoftwareLicensingService"
    Write-Debug 'Activating Windows.'
    $null = $KMSservice.InstallProductKey($key)
    $null = $KMSservice.SetKeyManagementServiceMachine($kms)
    $null = $KMSservice.RefreshLicenseStatus()
```

i got no issue with the '{{kms}}' var but only with ansible vars between powershell curly braces

ansible variables key1/2/3 are set into a var file.

thank you for your help!

Comment: What happens if you put them in quotes? `{$key = '{{key1}}'}`

Comment: The thing you'll want is [`{% raw %}`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#escaping) and `{% endraw %}` and then likely passing in the truly variable parts to powershell via [`environment:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#term-113)

Comment: hello, thank you for your solutions that I tested but it does not work better I still have errors but I found a workaround, by declaring the variables before powershell curly braces 
{
$2016std = '{{ key1 }}'
    $2016dtc = '{{ key2 }}'
    $2019dtc = '{{ key3 }}'
    $kms = '{{ kms }}'
    $OSversion = (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
    switch -Regex ($OSversion) {`